# ¿Esta mal hacer un método que solo pase a otro?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un Componente que tiene varios paneles y métodos dentro pero están en clases internas a este, quiero que al crear un objeto de ese componente pueda cambiar propiedades de esas clases, y se me ocurrió crear un método que llame a ese método de esta manera: (código de ejemplo para que se entienda el método que llama a otro)

```
public class Table {

    private Body body;
    
    public Table() {
        body = new Body();
    }

    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        body.setRowCount(rowCount);
    }

private class Body {
    
    private int rows;

    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        rows = rowCount;
    }

}

}
```

Se puede hacer métodos que dentro llamen a funciones pero esto es solo un pase de un método a otro, no se si tienen nombre este tipo de cosas, lo que se ve ahí es que hago un método que se ve desde afuera cuando creas el Objeto de la clase y lo llamas con:

> table.setRowCount(10);

Pero este método en su interior solo hace referencia a un método de la clase Body y ese si realiza cambios pero en la clase correspondiente, como por ejemplo cambiar el color de ese panel especifico del componente, o en este caso cambiar un valor numérico de este.

Lo he intentado y si se puede hacer esto, pero quiero saber lo siguiente:

¿Esta mal hacer esto? ¿Es una mala practica? ¿Se puede usar en un proyecto?

Comment: se puede hacer? si, de hecho lo estas haciendo... se puede usar en un proyecto? si, de hecho lo estas haciendo... es una mala practica.. y depende del contexto... esta mal? y.. depende del contexto.. y esta pregunta, son puras opiniones..

Comment: Puede que sea mejor resolver esto por medio de la herencia: Table < Body < Row < Cell

Comment: O, mejor aún mediante [Composición o Agregación](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/).

Comment: A mi me recuerda a un patrón de diseño, pero no recuerdo cuál ahora mismo... Como te dice @A.Cedano te va a depender del contexto de lo que quieras hacer en tu app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que propones **NO** está mal hacerlo y **NO** es una mala práctica, sino todo lo contrario.

Lo que estás haciendo es cumplir con la **[Ley de Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)** (no hables con extraños) o ***principio de menor conocimiento*** y de este modo fomentando el cumplimiento del principio de ***bajo acoplamiento***.

La **Ley de Demeter** es una guía para el diseño de sistemas software que brinda unas pautas para evitar el alto acoplamiento entre módulos. Podemos resumirla de estas tres formas (tomado de la Wikipedia y traducido por mí):

> - Cada unidad solo debería tener conocimiento limitado sobre otras unidades: solo unidades estrechamente relacionadas con la unidad actual.
> - Cada unidad solo debería hablar con amigos; no hables con extraños.
> - Solo habla con tus amigos inmediatos.

Entonces, si atendemos a lo anterior, tu solución cumple muy bien con esto puesto que evita que los clientes de la clase `Table` se acoplen a los detalles de implementación de esta para modificar su estado.

Lo contrario sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
class Frame {

    private Table table;

    public void removeAllItems() {
        // ...
        table.getBody().setRowCount(0);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver la clase `Frame` se está acoplando a la clase `Table.Body`, la cual no está estrechamente relacionada ella. Esto es muy problemático puesto que si en un futuro se cambia, o elimina, el nombre del método `Body#setRowCount()` o se reemplaza la clase `Body` por otra completamente diferente, nuestra clase se vería afectada.

Este ejemplo también se corresponde con un *smell code* mencionado por Martin Fowler en su libro **Refactoring. Improving the Design of Existing Code** llamado *Message Chains* o cadena de mensajes. El propio Martin Fowler propone lo que has hecho tú, como principal técnica de *refactoring* para solucionarlo: *Hide Delegate* u Ocultar Delegado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, acepto como que soluciono mi problema, no conocía esta Ley, responde a las preguntas que tenia, y se entiende muy claro, muchas gracias por la información

Comment: Un placer haberte ayudado @JFrame224.